# How do I find duplicates in an array and display how many times they occurred python?

Tags: python

```
a=[1,2,2,3,4]
dict={}

for i in a:
    dict[i]=1
    if i in dict:
         dict[i]=+1
        
    print(dict)
```

> I want to print highest frequency number on the above list & expecting output should be "2"

Comment: Try not to name your variable with builtin names likes `dict`, even for examples !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a correction of your code. It is a possible solution but like in the other answers already shown, it is a lot easier to accomplish with `collections.Counter`.

(1) You need to make an `if / else` statement. You set the value of your dict to 1 in every loop, regardless if it is already existent or not. (if you have a value in your list which count is bigger than 2, this will lead to wrong results)

(2) wrong syntax here: `=+` needs to be `+=`.

(3) don't name a variable same as build-in names. `dict` should not be a variable name. better: `dic` or `my_dict` etc.

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
dic = {}

for i in a:
    if i not in dic:
        dic[i] = 1
    else:
        dic[i] += 1

print(dic)

{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

You only want to get the key of the value which has the biggest frequency in your list. Therefore you need to use `max` with a key (you don't want to get the maximum of keys, you want to get the maximum of its values and return the key of that maximum.

```
result = max(dic.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1])
# this would return in this case a tuple with (key,value): (2, 2). you only want to get the key:
print(result[0])
# 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) method.

```py
from collections import Counter

a=[1,2,2,3,4]
a = Counter(a) # Counter Method returns a dictionary where's the value of key is the number if occurrence present in list.

# Here `a` is: Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})
number = max(a.items(),key=lambda e:e[1])
print(number[0]) # 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`Counter` is built for this:

```
from collections import Counter
a=[1,2,2,3,4]
counter=Counter(a)
k = max(counter, key=counter.get)
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is resetting the counter even if the number is already present in the dict. You could change it to:

```
a=[1,2,2,3,4]
counts=dict()

for i in a:
    if i in counts:
        counts[i]=+1
    else:
        counts[i]=1 
print(counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the dictionary by iterating through the list, to count the items

```
a = ['one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'four']
dic={}

for num in a:
    if num in dic.keys():
        dic[num] += 1
    else:
        dic[num] = 1
    
print({k: v for k, v in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)})
```

Output:

```
{'two': 2, 'one': 1, 'three': 1, 'four': 1}
```

The dictionary gets sorted in descending order (by value), so the highest occurrence is value 2.

By the way, try to avoid Python reserved words like `dict`, for example you will not be able to use below code when `dict` is used as a variable. Try to Restart Kernel so that you can use below code (same output):

```
dict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code.
In the output of this code a dictionary will be printed with keys: "Number" and "times" with there respective list each containing the numbers that have been repeated and the number of times they have been repeated respectively. Both the list are corresponding to each other.

```
a=[1,2,2,3,4]
b = []
c = {"Number" : [],
    "times" : []}
j = 0

for i in a:
    if i not in b:
        b.append(i) #Creating a copy of the original list with no repeation of the number.
    elif i in b:
        if i in c["Number"]:
            pass
        elif i not in c["Number"]:
            c["Number"].append(i) # Adding the repeating number into the dictionary under the key "Number".

for number in c["Number"]:
    for item in a:
        if item == number:
            j = j + 1 # counting the number of time the respective number repeated.
    c["times"].append(j) # Adding the number of repetitions into the dictionary under key "times".
    j = 0 
    
print(c)
```

The output of the following code:

```
{'Number': [2], 'times': [2]}
```

The values from the lists can also be extracted directly or as list as per the usage.
The program can also work with more numbers too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
def find_duplicate(a):
    # call counter in the collection library
    counter = collections.Counter(a)
    duplic = max(counter, key=counter.get)
    return duplic
a =[1,2,2,3,4]
print(find_duplicate(a))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?